# MySQL Replication threeway

Tags: mysql, cluster, replication, mysql-replication, database-replication

We have MySQL Multi-Master replication setup between two servers ( A & B ). It has been working for a few years now and life is good.

The management tool in our office connects directly to Server A to perform updates and selects. As you can imagine this is not the fastest, especially because our office internet connection is no good.

So I would like to replicate the whole database on our office server but do not want to do this...

A -> B -> C -> A

because C will be a bottleneck for replication between B & A

Is their a way to

A -> B -> A   AND   C -> A -> C

I only see examples for creating loops of servers in MySQL. We can not migrate to a different database at this stage, nor immediately abandon the existing replication between A & B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sandor said, this cannot be done with standard MySQL replication.  It *can* be done if you use a third-party / external replication mechanism.

A few products that I'm aware of:

[Continuent Tungsten Replicator](http://www.continuent.com/solutions/replication)

[SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/)

Both are open source and freely available.

Another option would be to migrate to a MySQL cluster.

Some options:

[MySQL Carrier Grade Edition](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/)

[Percona XtraDB Cluster](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster)

If you decide to investigate the cluster route the terms *multi-site replication* and *geographical replication* will help you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No.
That would require A to be slave to both B and C, which is not possible.
A-›B->C->A not recommended either.